# Rscript sees a different R version than the one installed

Tags: r, package, rstudio, rscript

I am trying to call an R script from inside Python however in the 1st line of the R script I am calling the "lubridate" library which gives me the following error

```
Error in readRDS(pfile) :   cannot read workspace version 3 written by R 4.0.2; need R 3.5.0 or newer Calls: library -> find.package -> lapply -> FUN -> readRDS Execution halted
```

After calling `.libPaths()` in Rstudio I find that the library directories are :

```
[1] "/zhome/c9/f/144817/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0" [2] "/appl/R/4.0.2-mkl2020/lib64/R/library"
```

However, I put the `print(.libPaths())` command at the first line of my R script and then run Rscript from inside my Python code, and the path that gives me is the following:

```
[1] "/appl/R/3.2.2/lib64/R/library"
```

It seems that the `.libPaths()` sees different library directories when called from Rstudio and when called from inside Python withe the `Rscript` command.

Any advice here, how I could make it look to the right library location?

Comment: It seems very likely that Python is not running the same R version as RStudio runs, and that's why it's using a different library.    You can print `R.version.string` to see what is running (or for lots more detail, run `sessionInfo()` ).  Why is Python running a different R version?  Most likely your `PATH` environment variable is pointing to it.

Comment: @user2554330 How I can then change the PATH env that Python sees the R version?